# still receiving CORS error in Spring altough CrossOrigin annotation is added to the controller

Tags: java, angular, spring, cors

I am developing a very basic spring application running with an angular frontend. I am getting following CORS error on my browser console, when i try to send a basic post or get request:

[image: console error]

My spring controller looks like this:

```
package com.unlockestate.ueparent.auth;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(UserRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.userRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Iterable<User> findAllUsers() {
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping("/createUser")
    public User addOneUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (this.userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) == null) {
            return this.userRepository.save(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

in application.properties i have:

server.servlet.contextPath=/ueapp

when i open http://localhost:8080/ueapp/users directly in browser it works as expected, but when i send a request from my angular frontend i get the cors error. i thought @CrossOrigin annotation suppose to solve that?

I would appreciate it, if someone could help me.

I also tried to add global crossorigin configuration but it doesnt help...

Comment: At some point, you might want to add some OAuth2 authorization and you might have to choose an architecture with SAMEORIGIN requests for that. See this article I wrote for details about why and how: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

Answer (score 1):

You can try configuring a Bean that will do the job for you like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    private static final Long MAX_AGE = 3600L;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilterFilterRegistrationBean() {
      
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); //you can add you origin url
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()));
        config.setMaxAge(MAX_AGE);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));

        // we need to CorsFilter before SpringSecurityFilter
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;

    }
```

This worked for me. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Probably it is the same reason why it is not working on individual controller level..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry apparently i had a typo in server.servlet.contextPath.... I realised the call i made to /ue-app/ context path and /ueapp/ doesnt fit.. It works now also with the global setting. thanks anyways and sorry again